# Ansible "Unexpected failure during module execution" error

Tags: ansible

### 1. Host file contents

```
[droplets]
host1 ansible_ssh_host=<IP1>
```

### 2. /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg contents:

```
inventory      = /etc/ansible/hosts
```

### 3. /etc/ansible/group_vars/droplets contents:

```
---
ansible_ssh_user: admin
```

### 4. Log on running the following command:

```
$ ansible -m ping host1 -vvv
```

Ansible 2.4.1.0

---

config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
>    mkdir(name, mode)
>   OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '~'

```
host1 | FAILED! => {
  "failed": true, 
  "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", 
  "stdout": ""
}
```

Appreciate if someone could help on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, "Ansible 2.0 has deprecated the “ssh” from ansible_ssh_user, ansible_ssh_host, and ansible_ssh_port to become ansible_user, ansible_host, and ansible_port. If you are using a version of Ansible prior to 2.0, you should continue using the older style variables (ansible_ssh_*). These shorter variables are ignored, without warning, in older versions of Ansible."

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable

Comment: Thanks for quick response.   I have changed references to ansible_ssh_user, ansible_ssh_host as suggested and still getting the same error.